# How do you "buffer" UNIX signals

Tags: c++, sockets, pthreads, signals

How does one buffer a UNIX signal in such a way blocking functions will unblock upon being called? In our software we use sockets. We now want to unblock/cancel a `recv()` call through a signal. The issue is that if the signal is being sent before `recv()` is entered, then it is lost and `recv()` never unblocks.

The main function looks like this:

```
bool signalHandlerSetup;
bool signalSent;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread;
    signalHandlerSetup = false;
    signalSent = false;

    // Block the SIGUSR1 signal in the main thread
    sigset_t signalSet;
    sigemptyset(&signalSet);
    sigaddset(&signalSet, SIGUSR1);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &signalSet, NULL);

    // Setup the signal handler for all future threads
    struct sigaction signalAction;
    signalAction.sa_flags = 0;
    signalAction.sa_handler = [](int signalNumber) {};
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &signalAction, NULL);

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, secondaryThreadFunction, NULL);
    std::cout << "Started thread" << std::endl;

    // Wait until the signal handler is setup
    while (!signalHandlerSetup);
    pthread_kill(thread, SIGUSR1);

    signalSent = true;
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    std::cout << "Joined thread" << std::endl;
}
```

The secondary thread just creates a socket and attempts to read from it:

```
void* secondaryThreadFunction(void *arg)
{
    // Setup socket
    int internSocket = setupSocket();

    // Setup the signal handling
    sigset_t signalSet;
    sigemptyset(&signalSet);
    sigaddset(&signalSet, SIGUSR1);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &signalSet, NULL);
    signalHandlerSetup = true;

    while (!signalSent);

    char buffer;
    std::cout << "recv()..." << std::endl;
    ssize_t bytesRead = recv(internSocket, static_cast<void*>(&buffer), sizeof(buffer), 0);
    std::cout << "recv() canceled" << std::endl;

    close(internSocket);
}
```

As you can see the signal is explicitly being sent before the `recv()` function is entered to illustrate the problem.

Apart from buffering, there might be other solutions to this but there are drawbacks to each of these:

- Wait until the secondary thread is blocked (Causes the main thread to block too or to busy loop)
- Constantly sending the signal (Another busy loop)

EDIT:
The socket should not be closed just to unblock the secondary thread. We might want to operate on the same socket again after unblocking.

EDIT 2:
I've been able to solve the problem with the solution provided by Martin James and Darren Smith. I am using the `select()` function in combination with an event file descriptor now. For reference here is the working solution:

```
int eventDescriptor;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread;

    // Create the event file descriptor
    eventDescriptor = eventfd(
        0,  // Initial value
        0   // Flags
    );
    if (eventDescriptor == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create event file descriptor" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, secondaryThreadFunction, NULL);
    std::cout << "Started thread" << std::endl;

    // Notify the event descriptor
    uint64_t valueToWrite = 1;
    if (write(eventDescriptor, &valueToWrite, sizeof(uint64_t)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to write to event file descriptor" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    std::cout << "Joined thread" << std::endl;

    close(eventDescriptor);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the secondary thread:

```
void* secondaryThreadFunction(void *arg)
{
    // Setup socket
    int internSocket = setupSocket();

    // Set up the file descriptor set
    fd_set readFileDescriptorSet;
    FD_ZERO(&readFileDescriptorSet);
    FD_SET(internSocket, &readFileDescriptorSet);
    FD_SET(eventDescriptor, &readFileDescriptorSet);

    char buffer;
    std::cout << "select()..." << std::endl;
    int fileDescriptorsSet = select(std::max(internSocket, eventDescriptor) + 1, &readFileDescriptorSet, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (FD_ISSET(eventDescriptor, &readFileDescriptorSet))
    {
        std::cout << "select() canceled via event" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (FD_ISSET(internSocket, &readFileDescriptorSet))
    {
        std::cout << "select() canceled through socket" << std::endl;
        ssize_t bytesRead = recv(internSocket, static_cast<void*>(&buffer), sizeof(buffer), 0);
    }

    close(internSocket);
}
```

Comment: @AlexF In the example code given the socket can be closed but in our software solution we just want the `recv()` function to unblock. Later on we might want to operate on the same socket again. Therefore, the socket should not be closed.

Comment: select() before recv()?  Wait on the fd and a semaphore.  SIgnal the semaphore from the signal handler - if the sema is signaled before the select is reached, the select will still return 'immediately' because the sema has retained the count value.

Comment: `std::cout` means this code is C++, not C.

Comment: You can also use pselect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider doing the following (similar to MartinJames suggestion in comments).

Restructure your secondary thread so that instead of doing direct blocking calls of `recv()`, you replace it with blocking call to one of the file-based event loops (e.g., `epoll`, or `select`)

The blocking call will listen for events on **two** file descriptions:

(1) the file descriptor of the socket (`internSocket`)

(2) a new file descriptor created by `eventfd()`

In your main function you will create the event file descriptor by calling `eventfd()`.  When a signal arrives, write a value to the event file descriptor; that will cause the blocked thread to resume out of the select wait.

Basic example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/eventfd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void write_to_eventfd(int fd) {
  /* we must write an 8 byte integet to the eventfd. */
  uint64_t u = 1;
  if (-1 == write(fd, &u, sizeof(uint64_t)))
    perror("write()");
}

int main()
{
  /* create event file descriptor */
  int efd = eventfd(0, 0);
  if (efd == -1)
    perror("eventfd()");

  /* For example purpose, do an immediate write; this causes select() to
   * immediately return (simulate signal arrive before socket read). Later
   * perform this in separate thread upon signal arrival. */
  write_to_eventfd(efd);

  /* Watch stdin (fd 0) to see when it has input.  Watch the eventfd for an
   * event.  Add other socket file descriptors etc. */
  fd_set rfds;
  FD_ZERO(&rfds);
  FD_SET(0, &rfds);
  FD_SET(efd, &rfds);

  /* Blocking read */
  int retval = select(efd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  if (retval == -1)
    perror("select()");

  if (FD_ISSET(efd, &rfds))
    printf("event!\n"); /* next: read the value from efd */

  if (FD_ISSET(0, &rfds))
    printf("some data on fd(0)\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Also consider the other event loops.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to "unblock `recv`". Instead, use non-blocking `recv`, and use [`ppoll`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ppoll) to block which is designed for this purpose. (`pselect` can also be used)

Set up a `struct pollfd`:

```
struct pollfd pollfd = {.fd = internSocket, .events = POLLIN};
```

**Block** the signal until you are ready to receive it:

```
sigset_t signalSet;
sigemptyset(&signalSet);
sigaddset(&signalSet, SIGUSR1);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &signalSet, NULL);
```

Prepare a signal set with the signal unblocked:

```
pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK /* ignored when second parameter is null */, NULL, &signalSet);
sigdelset(&signalSet, SIGUSR1);
```

Call `ppoll` to block:

```
int ppoll_result = ppoll(&pollfd, 1, NULL /* no timeout */, &signalSet);
```

Check whether `ppoll` was interrupted by a signal, or whether you got any data:

```
if (ppoll_result < 0) {
    if (errno == EINTR) {
        // interrupted by signal
    } else {
        // error occurred
    }

} else {
    assert(ppoll_result == 1); // Should always be true, but it's a good idea to check anyway

    // call recv
}
```

Note: generally when using `poll`/`ppoll` we would check `pollfd.events` to see what type of events caused it to wake up, but this is not necessary since you are only waiting for one socket. It is possible to wait for more than one socket at a time when using `poll`/`ppoll`.

Note: This is not the only way to wait for a signal with `poll`. You could use [`signalfd`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signalfd), which "converts" signals into something that looks like a socket.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `signalfd` that buffers the signals for you, no need to install a signal handler. See the example in [`man signalfd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html).

You will need to use `select`/`poll`/`epoll` event loop to wait till the signal or your socket fd are ready for read and then read them in non-blocking mode until `EAGAIN`, like the other answers here advise.